# where are gstreamer bus message types listed?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Is there some list of all message types?
I wanted to add signal callback for certain message type on bus, but did not know what is the name of the signal - it happened on the bus emitted probably from the pipeline itself. Finally I found  out that the name was new-clock but I had a hard time finding this out (greping through bus debug messages).

Is there some list of known message names?
I know that there are messages like eos, element, new-clock ..

I am connecting to callbacks like this:

```
g_signal_connect (bus, "message::eos", G_CALLBACK (callback_eos), this);
```

If there is no such list how would you searched for message like new-clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive from the message types here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMessage.html#GstMessageType

Or just look at the quark strings at the source: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/gst/gstmessage.c#n73

Comment: looks good, so the rule is get the name NEW_CLOCK and convert to lowercase and underscore _ to dash - thus we have new-clock thanks